# How to resize data grid in C# windows Application

Tags: c#

When maximizing a Windows form I need to maximize a dataGrid, as well.

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Control.Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)

> Use the Anchor property to define how
>   a control is automatically resized as
>   its parent control is resized.
>   Anchoring a control to its parent
>   control ensures that the anchored
>   edges remain in the same position
>   relative to the edges of the parent
>   control when the parent control is
>   resized.

Comment: +1 @Aravind: To achieve the effect you're looking for, you'll want to anchor the `DataGrid` on all sides (Left, Top, Right, Bottom).

Comment: yeah, anchor and/or dock is a beautiful thing of .Net winform.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties. If the data grid is the only control on the form you can set the Dock property to `Fill`.